# Download email, save attachment to working directory

Tags: java, email, email-attachments

Is there some way to do this?   I'm getting a daily email with a .csv attachment, but I'm not sure how to download the mail or the attachment using only java.

Are there any good libraries that handle this sort of thing?   Or some source code that may help me in this process?   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into using the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) API.

I would also advise you to look at [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155504/download-mail-attachment-with-java) if you need some source code to get you started.